# Site and module specific user authentication in yii

Tags: php, yii, authentication

So, I have one module ( admin ) and the main site. I want to separate the authentication. If I'm loged in with an account authenticated in the admin module the main site gets this user data and I dont want this.

So what can a I do to separate the authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the init method of your module, change the [CWebUser stateKeyPrefix](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#stateKeyPrefix-detail). Anything regarding authentication after that will use different variables in the session.
So basically 1 session will store the login for both users, but use different variables:

```
class AdminModule extends CWebModule
{
    public function init()
    {
         Yii::app()->user->stateKeyPrefix = 'admin';
         parent::init();
    }
}
```